# MIPS core dump with ra and pc equal 0000000

Tags: gdb, mips, coredump

I'm getting intermittent core dumps in one of our processes.
All of the threads' stacks, aside from the one which crashed, seem OK, and parsed correctly.

The thread that crashes has an apparently corrupted call stack.
The stack is has two frames, both of them 0x00000000.
Looking on the registers, both PC and RA are 0 (which explains the call stack...)
The cause register is 00800008.

1. Is there a way I can get more information on the crashed thread?
2. How come the registers themselves are corrupted? (Or is it the other way around, in core dump the debugger fills these registers based on the stack?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To answer (2) first -- because understanding what actually happened is important for finding out more information about the root cause of the crash:

It really is the registers themselves, in the machine at runtime, that are 0; but it's not that the registers themselves got corrupted; rather, memory got corrupted, and that corrupted memory then got copied back into the registers, which finally caused the crash.

What's happening is something like this: the stack becomes corrupted, including (a) specifically the RA, *while it is stored on the stack memory*, gets zeroed out. Then, when the function is ready to return, it (b) restores the RA register from the stack -- so the RA *register* is now 0 -- and then (c) jump-returns to the RA, thus setting the PC to also point to 0; the next instruction will then cause a crash, while both the RA and PC are 0.

That business about the RA being stored on the stack and then restored from it is explained, for example, at http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm (emphasis mine):

> return address stored in register $ra; if subroutine will call other subroutines, or is
>   recursive, **return address should be copied from $ra onto stack to preserve it**, 
>   since jal always places return address in this register and hence will overwrite 
>   previous value.

Here's an example program which crashes with PC and RA both 0, and which illustrates the above sequence nicely (the exact numbers may have to be tweaked, depending on the system):

```
#include <string.h>

int bar(void)
{
    char buf[10] = "ABCDEFGHI";
    memset(buf, 0, 50);
    return 0;
}

int foo(void)
{
    return bar();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return foo();
}
```

And if we look at the disassembly of foo():

```
(gdb) disas foo
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
   0x00400408 <+0>:     addiu   sp,sp,-32
   0x0040040c <+4>:     sw      ra,28(sp)
   0x00400410 <+8>:     sw      s8,24(sp)
   0x00400414 <+12>:    move    s8,sp
   0x00400418 <+16>:    jal     0x4003a0 <bar>
   0x0040041c <+20>:    nop
   0x00400420 <+24>:    move    sp,s8
   0x00400424 <+28>:    lw      ra,28(sp)
   0x00400428 <+32>:    lw      s8,24(sp)
   0x0040042c <+36>:    addiu   sp,sp,32
   0x00400430 <+40>:    jr      ra
   0x00400434 <+44>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
```

we see very nicely that RA gets stored on the stack at the beginning of the function (`<+4> sw ra,28(sp)`) and then is restored at the end (`<+28> lw ra,28(sp)`) and then jump-returned to (`<+40> jr ra`). I showed foo() because it's shorter, but the exact same structure is true for bar() -- except that in bar() there is also the memset() in the middle, which overwrites RA while it is on the stack (it's writing 50 bytes into an array of size 10); and then what gets restored into the register is 0, ultimately causing the crash.

So, now we understand that the root cause of the crash is some kind of stack corruption, which gets us back to question (1): is there any way way to get more information about the crashed thread?

Well, this is a bit more difficult, and is where debugging becomes more of an art than a science, but here are the principles to keep in mind:

- The basic idea is to figure out what is causing the stack corruption -- most likely, it is a write to some local buffer, as in the example above.
- Try to zero in as much as possible on where in the flow the corruption is occurring. Logging can help a lot here: the last log you see obviously happened before the crash (though not necessarily before the corruption!) -- add more logging in the suspect area to zero in on the crash location. Of course, if you have access to a debugger, you can also step through the code to figure out where it's crashing.
- Once you find the crash location, it's much easier to work backwards from there: first of all, before the crash, the PC is not yet set to 0, and therefore you should be able to see a backtrace (though, note that the backtrace itself is "calculated" using the values stored *on the stack* -- once they are corrupted, the backtrace can't be calculated beyond the corruption. But this is actually helpful in this case: this can tell you quite precisely where in memory the *corruption* is: the point at which the backtrace is truncated is the RA (on the stack) which got corrupted.)
- Once you have found what is being corrupted, but you still don't know what is causing the corruption, use watchpoints: as soon as you enter the function which places the RA that is ultimately overwritten on the stack, set a watchpoint on it. That should cause a break as soon as the corruption occurs...

Hope this helps!